# Select and Checkbox calculator keeps giving NaN unless both select's are ticked

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, calculator, nan

I have a calculator which keeps giving NaN unless both select's (dropdowns) have an option selected.

Originally this was working fine with one select box and two check boxes as can be seen here https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/NZqdXg

I then tried to make it so it had two drop down's but I get a NaN unless both dropdowns have a selection - This can be seen here https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/ewNBPR

Note: I am not sure if this matters, but this is also based on conditional logic as can be seen here https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/JQdGWG

My Script:

```
$(function(){


  $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
  $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
  $("select.thisone").on("change", calc);

  function calc() {
   var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.calculate option:selected,  select.thisone option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  }
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<label>How long do you want the cover?</label>
  <select  name="howlongcover" class="thisone" >
       <option>Pick one!</option>
      <option data-price="55" value="valuhowlongcover"  >24 Months a </option>
      <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="58" >36 Months</option>
 <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="71" >48 Months</option>
  <option  value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="119" >60 Months</option>

    </select>
 <label>How long do you want the cover 2?</label>
  <select class="calculate" name="howlongcover">


       <option>Pick one!</option>
      <option  value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="60" >24 Months b </option>
      <option value="valuhowlongcover"data-price="65" >36 Months</option>
 <option  value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="79" >48 Months</option>
  <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="139" >60 Months</option>

    </select>

<BR><BR>


 Please tick if any of the following apply<br>
  <label><input class="calculate"  type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"><span></span> It's classed as a 4x4</label><BR>
  <label><input class="calculate"  type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"><span></span> The engine is more than 2.5L</label><BR>
    <label><class="calculate"  type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"><span></span> It's a commercial use</label><BR>

      <BR>
     Price:  <span id="item-price">0</span>
```

When I added

```
$("select.thisone").on("change", calc);
```

and

```
$("select.calculate option:selected,  select.thisone option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });
```

and

```
<select  name="howlongcover" class="thisone" >
```

This is when I started facing issues with NaN and having to have both dropdowns selected. (which in the form will never have both dropdowns selected because the conditional logic will never show both)

Please see this pen https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/ewNBPR

EDIT: Fully working codepen is here https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/ZdGLZm Only one dropdown works on this one.. "up to £15,000" and then select cover works in calculator. Reason I am showing this is so you can see what I am trying to accomplish

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting NaN because whenever any input checkbox is clicked, you fire the calc() function. The calc() function gets the selected options data as well as the checkboxes data and tries to parse an int from it. The problem is, the default option you have selected is the "Pick One!" which doesn't have any data-price attribute set; so when going through your for each loop...

```
$("select.calculate option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
    newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
});
```

... when "this" refers to the selected option "Pick One!", $(this).data('price') will in turn return undefined as that option has no data-price attribute. So if you leave it at that, and click either checkbox, the calc() function will try and parse an int from undefined which will return NaN, as you cannot parse integers from something that is undefined.

You could remove that option entirely, add a data-price="0" attribute on the "Pick One!" option, or you could add some conditional statement to make sure the selected option is a number:

```
function calc() {
var basePrice = 0;
newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      if(typeof $(this).data('price') === "number"){
        newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
      }
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
```

}

Comment: Thank you Musilix, Very clear explanation! I have done as you suggested and added data-price="0" to the "Pick one!" Option. Thank you so much.